# JavaScript onclick event works only as double-click

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick

I'm writing because I need to solve this problem. Until recently, the code was working just fine and I've been using it for quite a long time, but yesterday, when I was testing the page, everything changed.

The idea is click on an image with an anchor tag that is going to redirect the user to another page and in doing so, a confirm dialog box should pop up to ask the person whether they want that. I haven't changed anything in the code, so I'm not getting what's happening. Here's the code:

```js
// **JavaScript**
function confPopUp() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("redPic")[i].onclick = redConf;
  }
}

function redConf() {
  var conf = confirm(
    "You're about to be redirected to our social media page. Do you accept?"
  );
  if (conf) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

window.onclick = confPopUp;
```

```html
<!-- **HTML** //THERE ARE 5 MORE ELEMENTS WITH THE CLASS NAME "redPic". -->

<a href="https://www.madridsolutions.es" target="_blank"><img class="redPic" src="images/instagramLogo.png" alt="Instagram Logo"></a>
```

The problem is that I'm testing it, right now, and it's not working properly, a the day before yesterday it was working fine, only one click and now, it's working as double-click.
I'd appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: What is happening is that you are adding the click listener inside the window click listener. So initially only the window listens for a click. Then when clicking anywhere the `onclick` is set on the `.redPic` elements. So now when you click on the images the `redConf` function is being called. Hence, you have to click twice.

Comment: Thanks for your time, Mr. Zuurbier. Your answer also helped a lot.

Answer (score 3):

When the page first loads, you're setting a **single** event handler:

```
window.onclick=confPopUp;
```

Later, when there's a click anywhere in the window, that runs your `confPopUp` function, which hooks up the click handlers on the `.redPic` elements.

Later, if you click a `.redPic` element, your `redConf` function runs.

If you want the `.redPic` elements to have their handlers hooked up on page load, **call** `confPopUp` instead of making it a click handler. Change:

```
window.onclick=confPopUp;
```

to

```
confPopUp();
```

Be sure this code is running **after** the `.redPic` elements exist. There are several ways to do that, pick the one that suits your target browsers and preference:

1. Put the code in a `script` tag at the end of the document, just before the closing `</body>` tag. This works with all browsers, no matter how old.
2. In even vaguely-modern browsers, call `confPopUp` from a `DOMContentLoaded` event handler:

   ```
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", confPopUp);
   ```
3. In modern browsers, add a `defer` attribute to your `script` tag.
4. In modern browsers, add `type="module"` to your `script` tag to make your script a module. That defers it just like `defer` does, **and** puts it in strict mode (which is a good idea), and put the code in it in module scope rather than global scope (which is really crowded).

---

So why did it seem to work yesterday? Presumably, because you were clicking the window without realizing it, triggering that initial event handler that hooked up the `.redPic` elements. Today it just happened that you didn't click the window before trying to click a `.redPic` element, so you discovered this problem. The problem's been there all along.

Comment: Many thanks, Mr. Crowder. Your answer just solved the problem.